# Proper permissions, ownership to allow php to parse contents of file but disallow access from web browser

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a file with sensitive data in it that I parse in php as follows:

```
define('__PATHSECRET__', dirname(__ROOT__) . '/secretstuff');
$credFilePath = __PATHSECRET__ . '/credentials.ini'; 
$credArray = parse_ini_file($credFilePath);
```

**How should I set the permissions on the directory and file so that I can parse the file using the code above, but prevent the contents of that file from being displayed in the web browser?**

- linux server
- php runs as 'root'
- apache runs as 'apache'
- The only file in the secretstuff directory is credentials.ini
- I do not have access to modifying apache or php settings

I can't seem to get the right combination of ownership and permissions.  I either end up with 'permission denied' on the parse_ini_file command or I'm able to browse the contents of the credentials.ini file.

Comment: Is the file in your webroot? You can move it outside your webroot

Comment: is it possible to do this without moving the file out of webroot?  if that's the only way, i can probably get access to do that.

Comment: Well, if you it is in your webroot and you give read permission to apache it can be displayed in browser, if you don't apache php module won't be able to read it. Also make sure that apache auto index is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not limited to `.ini` extension, you can change it to `.php` and comment out the first line as both ini-comment and PHP multiline comment and the last line as ini-comment and closing PHP multiline comment:

```
; <?php /*
[section1]
parameter = value

[section2]
parameter.foo = bar

; */
```

It will allow you to use `parse_ini_file()` and show only `;`, if you request this file with browser.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the ini file under your webroot at all--it can be anywhere on the system. As for leaving it under the webroot but blocking its display, you can do this inside your Apache configuration or with a `.htaccess` file, and leave the UNIX file permissions alone:

```
<Directory "/var/www/secretstuff">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```